# Unable to fetch the token from another thread group in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, postman, token

In **HTTP Request**, I gave login credentials then login got success, access_token generated.
Then by using **JSON Extractor**, I extracted the access_token and name as "auth_token".
Then in **Beanshell Assertion**, I added script "${__setProperty(auth_token, ${auth_token})};"
Then in **HTTP Request Defaults**, I added Parameter "Authorization"  "${__property(auth_token)}" (in Test Plan level)

I cannot fetch that token in Thread_group-2, which is generated in Thread_group-1.

suggestions, please??

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to ensure that the Thread Group which extracts the token is executed **before** the Thread Group which uses the token, either tick "Run Thread Groups consecutively" on Test Plan level:

   [image]

   or switch to [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) which is being executed before all "main" Thread Groups
2. In general you should not be passing values between Thread Groups as thread group represents a logical group of business users and authentication/authorization is an integral part of the business flow so my expectation is that you need to have authentication and other actions in the single Thread Group. If you want to perform authentication only once - put it under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
3. [Using Beanshell is kind of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider moving to JSR223 Test Elements instead.
4. I also have doubts regarding correctness of your token usage, I think you should rather use [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) instead and configure it to pass [Authorization](https://develoaper.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of [`Bearer`](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/) followed by whitespace followed by your token